# How to return an EnumMap if the keys are private

Tags: java

Here's a snippet of code I'm working on:

```
package testPack.model;

public class Person {
        private static enum Field {
            NAME, ALIASES, DATE_OF_BIRTH, DATE_OF_DEATH;
        }

        private EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>> lastUpdateTime;
        private Name name;
        private ArrayList<String> aliases;
        private Optional<LocalDate> dateOfBirth;
        private Optional<LocalDate> dateOfDeath;

        public final EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>> getUpdateTimes() {
            // Return a copy to avoid external changes to person
            return new EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>>(lastUpdateTime);
        }   
    }
```

The purpose of the `Field` enum is to keep track of the last time the fields of Person were updated. How can I make it so that another class can call `getUpdateTimes` and operate on the return without having access to `Fields`. To be specific, I want to be able to iterate over the values as well as get a specific value. Do I need to make Field public, and if so how can I use field without needing to import it (i.e. how do I avoid having to do `import testpack.model.Person.Field`)?

Comment: Is the root of your problem that you don't want to use an `import` statement?

Comment: I don't mind using an import statement, but it seems clunky to do 'import testpack.model.Person.Field' as well as 'import testpack.model.Person'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at least going to have to import the Person class. If you make the enum public, you should be able to access it from a class in a different package (and iterate through the keys as you say) as follows:

```
import testPack.model.Person;
...
Person person = new Person();
...
Map<Person.Field, Optional<Instant>> updateTimes = person.getUpdateTimes();
for (Person.Field field : updateTimes.keySet())
{
    ... // do something with the key
}
```

You can avoid the import, if that's really a requirement, by putting the two classes in the same package.

Comment: I thought I tried this at some point but ended up having to import both Person and Person.Field, but apparently it works now :|. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You would only have to import both if you wanted to use the Field enum without prefixing it with the Person classname. If this answer is what you were looking for, please feel free to mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this?

Have the enum in Field.java

```
package testPack.model;

public enum Field {
    NAME, ALIASES, DATE_OF_BIRTH, DATE_OF_DEATH;
}
```

Have a separate Person.java file

```
package testPack.model;

    public class Person {
        private static Field field;

        private EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>> lastUpdateTime;
        private Name name;
        private ArrayList<String> aliases;
        private Optional<LocalDate> dateOfBirth;
        private Optional<LocalDate> dateOfDeath;

        public final EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>> getUpdateTimes() {
            // Return a copy to avoid external changes to person
            return new EnumMap<Field, Optional<Instant>>(lastUpdateTime);
        }
    }
```

And, import the packages.class accordingly.

Also, it the makes the code loosely coupled